# Using php imap_search with FROM option and hotmail account

Tags: php, imap

I have successfully connected to my hotmail account, but when I try to do any sort of imap_search with the 'FROM' option, the webpage runs forever and then later chrome asks to kill the page. imap_search works with the 'ALL' option. Also the 'FROM' option worked with my gmail and yahoo account. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
$inbox = imap_open("{pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "example@hotmail.com", "password")or die(imap_last_error())or die("can't connect: ".imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM "example@example.com"');
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: Anyone who wants to do imap_search for hotmail acount, connect to this server: imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert instead. That server works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by hand:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect pop3.live.com:995 -crlf
...
+OK COL0-POP187 POP3 server ready
```

"POP3 server ready". So it's a POP3 server, not an IMAP server. No surprise, since the hostname says "pop3" and the port number is 995.

As far as I can tell, Hotmail does not provide IMAP access.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps. Also I was able to do imap_search($inbox, 'ALL'). It just has an issue with the FROM option.

Comment: Your imap_search() function is able to connect to a POP server and list all mail. But POP doesn't allow searching. For that your imap_search() function would need to connect to an actual IMAP server.

Comment: I'll add another comment: It's %$%!$%# stupid for imap_* functions to work without IMAP. That behaviour would be optimal, if the goal to mislead users and obscure mistakes such as the one in this question. *sigh*